# Can malware be transferred from an Android device to a Desktop computer?

Tags: malware, android, virus, infection-vector

I am curious if it's possible for Malware to be transferred from an Android device to a Desktop Computer.

In my situation I had detected malware on my android device via Lookout, and promptly deleted the infected app; however I had already opened the app by the time of malware detection.  There was no malware found on the device after deleting the app(according to Lookout), but I am skeptical that it's just "gone."  There was no weird popups or sms spam or anything, so not sure if it's just a background malware, or if it really is gone.

I was looking at these questions.

[Does it matter which platform a file is scanned on for malware?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/81192/does-it-matter-which-platform-a-file-is-scanned-on-for-malware)

[Known windows malware propagated via unmounted iPhone](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/58115/known-windows-malware-propagated-via-unmounted-iphone)

which from the Iphone question it seems that people say you cannot transfer malware via an Iphone, but what about an Android device?

The first link says that known AV programs will detect malware from other devices, so I would assume if it was in my Android device, I would have detected it while connected to my Desktop computer(s)?

Essentially, I'm looking to make sure that if malware had infected my device, that I had not transferred it to one of my desktop computers, or that it didn't infect my SD drive, which could infect the desktop computer, or even another phone.

Answer (score 2):

Your question basically boils down to, is it possible for any compromised device to infect other devices?

To which the only real answer is *yes*, it is *possible*. Unlikely perhaps, but possible.

Also, there is really no way of truly knowing if a device has been compromised, antivirus scan or not.

Answer (score 0):

Possibile but not so probable.

Malware (not APT) are typically very focused software. So they are developed to be executed on a specific target platform and obtain all the data they need to get money. Once the malware is on your mobile it has all the power to steal your private information and money. Much more than private data that are on your desktop nowadays.

Meanwhile an APT has a different scope: to gain private information and propagate as much as possible (but in a precise way) to spy more and more on you and your connection.

Malware are developer by cyber criminals, APT are developed (or committed) by governments.

IMHO

Answer (score 0):

When security is brought up with "IFs", "will it happen", "is it possible for xyz" the assumption for you should always be "YES" it is always possible for something to happen. Especially for malicious code, executables, infected devices and any machine with open ports or very insecure systems no based on purely security principles there is always a chance for one device to then infect other devices.

Also if you think a device is compromised please remove it from your network and start looking to how it could be compromised. Then start looking with devices that were connected to it. Maybe factory reset the devices such as android devices just the ones in contact or the ones that also were connected to the assumed compromised device. **QUARANTINE the devices assumed to be compromised.**

Rule of thumb assume nothing is safe and assume what you think might happen could happen. By that logic please change settings, remove capabilities of devices and user access to the minimalist way for access to assets in your house, organization, company or business structure.